# ERROR: `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I started programming in React Native, and I don't know how to fix this problem in code.

```html
<View style={styles.entradas}>
  <TextInput placeholder="Massa" keyboardType="numeric" style={styles.input} />
  <TextInput placeholder="Altura" keyboardType="numeric" style={styles.input} />

  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}><text style={styles.buttonText}>Calcular</text></TouchableOpacity>
  <text style={styles.resultado}></text>
  <text style={styles.resultado}></text>
</View>
```

when I run the code, I get this:

```js
The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
    in text (at App.js:65)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (at App.js:65)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (at App.js:60)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.web.js:10)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at registerRootComponent.web.js:6)
    in RootComponent
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Comment: What does your style object look like? The one you are passing into the component?